# Integrating redux with aws-appsync

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-native, aws-appsync

Is there any way to integrate redux with aws-appsync in react-native? 
If there is can you give me hint or clue on how to do it? I'm having a hard time integrating it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to connect your own redux store as is detailed in their documentation. Basically create your own  and use `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` from `react-redux` to connect your components.

```
const MyComponent = props => <h1>HI!</h1>
const ReduxConnected = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
const GraphQLConnected = graphql(gql`query { hi }`)(ReduxConnected)
```

And then at the root of your application have

```
import AWSAppSyncClient from "aws-appsync";
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux'
import { graphql, ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { Rehydrated } from 'aws-appsync-react';
import { createStore } from 'redux'


const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({...})
const store = createStore({...})

const ConnectedApp = () => 
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Rehydrated>
      <ReduxProvider store={store}>
        <App />
      </ReduxProvider>
    </Rehydrated>
  </ApolloProvider>
```

I haven't had a chance to try this setup but I will soon and will edit with any findings. In the meantime here is a link showing how to build a full RN app with AppSync that uses MobX instead of Redux (https://github.com/dabit3/heard) that may also be a good place to start.